# Symfony PHP - Redirect from within a service

Tags: php, symfony, service, symfony4, php-7.1

I have a Symfony 4 app with an authorization service which I would like to handle some higher level logic for whether or not a given user has access to a given route.

Im implementing this in a `BaseController`

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use App\Services\Authorize;

class BaseController extends Controller {

    private $auth;

    public function __construct(Authorize $auth){

        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function initBaseController() {

        $this->auth->do_authorize();
    }      
}
```

And the `Authorize` service looks like this:

```
namespace App\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use App\Services\Session;

class Authorize {

    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session){

        $this->session  = $session;
    }

    public function do_authorize(){

        if($this->session->validate('fake_token'){

            return $this->redirectToRoute('login-portal'); // ** ERROR **
        }

    }

}
```

So the idea is to implementing this process globally using the `BaseController` and redirect to the login page if a session doesnt exist or is not valid using `Authorize` service.

But the redirect line throws an error despite this being the correct implementation in the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting) on this topic.

I believe this is the case because I am trying to redirect from within a service, rather than a controller.

How would one redirect from within a service?

Comment: What does _ERROR_ mean ? 90% of required elements to figure out any hint or answer is contained in the error. So you SHOULD post the error message.

Answer (score 5):

Don't. Return `true` or `false` and redirect from controller

```
public function initBaseController()
{
    $auth = $this->auth->do_authorize();
    if($auth) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('login-portal');
    }
}


public function do_authorize()
{
    return $this->session->validate('fake_token');
}
```

The controller is responsible to do the redirects, not other layer.

Comment: ok I suppose this would better fall in the scope of the controller. but suppose I wanted to access some other such function in the service. how could I get around this limitation?

Comment: It's not a "limitation", it's software architecture. Each layer is responsible to do some things. Model (or repository) will access database. Service will contain business logic. View interacts with user. Controller get data from user and call the appropriete service. You can call the other function from the service, or the service can call multiple functions from another service and return to the controller.

Comment: Bools are "values" about a specific thing that was or is true or false, not control methods. So unless your Service class is called "RedirectIfSomethingWasSuccess" then a bool to determine to redirect or not is not clean. It actually goes against your argument "controller is responsible to do the redirect" - your service IS controlling the redirect based on the bool it returns